# How do I assign all members a role at once in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, assign

I'm trying to make a command with my bot that has an 'assignall' command, which will give every member in the server a role specified. This is what I have currently:

```py
import discord
import discord.utils
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ["nik!", "NIK!", "Nik!", "nIk!", "nIK!", "NIk!", "niK!", "NiK!"], help_command=None, case_insensitive=True)

@client.command(aliases = ['assigna'])
async def assignall(ctx, * role: discord.Role):
  if (not ctx.author.guild_permissions.manage_roles):
    await ctx.reply("Error: User is missing permission `Manage Roles`")
    return
  await ctx.reply("Attempting to assign all members that role...")
  for member in ctx.guild.members:
    try:
      await member.add_roles(role)
    except:
      await ctx.reply("Error: Can not assign role!\n"
      "Potential fix: Try moving my role above the role you want to assign to all members.")
  await ctx.reply("I have successfully assigned all members that role!")

client.run("tokenthaticantshowobviously")
```

Here's the exception:

```py
Ignoring exception in command assignall:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 91, in assignall
    await member.add_roles(role)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 777, in add_roles
  await req(guild_id, user_id, role.id, reason=reason)
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'id'
```

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: I'm not getting an error message in the console, I'm just getting the error message that I coded it in to say in the server. I'll edit the message and specify that.

Comment: People can only guess at what's wrong without a relevant error message. Try logging the exception.

Comment: I added the exception. Is there anything you can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cause of the asterisk before the `role` argument `discord.py` is processing it as a tuple instead of a `discord.Role` object. If you put a comma between the asterisk and the argument it'll work as intended.

```py
async def assignall(ctx, *, role: discord.Role):
```

Comment: That didn't work, sadly.
It just said that it had assigned all members the role but actually done nothing.

Comment: you need to enable members intents, see https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intents.html#a-primer-to-gateway-intents and https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intents.html#privileged-intents

Comment: I enabled the members gateway intent and it worked! Thank you for your help.